# How to assign a byte array to a class property in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need clarification on whether can we assign byte array to class Property in VB.Net. In my application, there is a byte array like given below:

```
  Public byte2() As Byte = Nothing
```

Now, I want to assign this array to a property of this class.

```
Public Class Form2

    Private bytval As Byte()
    Public Property NewProperty() As Byte()
        Get
            Return bytval
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte())
            bytval = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Now, I want assign the byte array to property like below:

```
obj.NewProperty()= byte2()
```

Is there any other way to assign an property array to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this to assign... Don't include the brackets

```
obj.NewProperty = byte2
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me in the same form but the property us empty if i use intialise in other form